# WooCommerce subcategories(categories of categories) - A tale of php, stupidly limited functions and frustration

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

The title should give you a pretty good idea about my misadventures. I am working on a project that's made in wordpress and uses WooCommerce, and after a lot of brainstorming and thought about possible compromise, i have reached the point where i am pretty much certain i have to get into the php code to solve the problem conveniently.

The problem is that i have the following website:

[image]

As you may have noticed, there is a mash of all the product categories, and what i need to do is split them into 2 main categories: food and drink. I turned what woocommerce can do by its built in functions and i just can't get it to work so i figured i'd have to write my own function. Now if any of you knows that i can actually do it with what i have i'd be happy if somebody told me. If not what i need is to create a function which can actually select all the categories belonging to a parent category or something the likes.

```
public function product_categories( $atts ) {
        global $woocommerce_loop;

        extract( shortcode_atts( array (
            'number'     => null,
            'orderby'    => 'name',
            'order'      => 'ASC',
            'columns'    => '4',
            'hide_empty' => 1,
            'parent'     => ''
            ), $atts ) );

        if ( isset( $atts[ 'ids' ] ) ) {
            $ids = explode( ',', $atts[ 'ids' ] );
            $ids = array_map( 'trim', $ids );
        } else {
            $ids = array();
        }

        $hide_empty = ( $hide_empty == true || $hide_empty == 1 ) ? 1 : 0;

        // get terms and workaround WP bug with parents/pad counts
        $args = array(
            'orderby'    => $orderby,
            'order'      => $order,
            'hide_empty' => $hide_empty,
            'include'    => $ids,
            'pad_counts' => true,
            'child_of'   => $parent
        );

        $product_categories = get_terms( 'product_cat', $args );

        if ( $parent !== "" )
            $product_categories = wp_list_filter( $product_categories, array( 'parent' => $parent ) );

        if ( $number )
            $product_categories = array_slice( $product_categories, 0, $number );

        $woocommerce_loop['columns'] = $columns;

        ob_start();

        // Reset loop/columns globals when starting a new loop
        $woocommerce_loop['loop'] = $woocommerce_loop['column'] = '';

        if ( $product_categories ) {

            woocommerce_product_loop_start();

            foreach ( $product_categories as $category ) {

                woocommerce_get_template( 'content-product_cat.php', array(
                    'category' => $category
                ) );

            }

            woocommerce_product_loop_end();

        }

        woocommerce_reset_loop();

        return '<div class="woocommerce">' . ob_get_clean() . '</div>';
    }
```

This i identified as the menacing WooCommerce function that does not behave. Help. Please help me :(

Answer (score 2):

What about using WooCommerce's built-in `[product_categories]` shortcode? You could pass categories you want through the `id=""` attribute.